# Parse Error: Syntax Error, unexpected ',' in C:// on line 14

Tags: php, syntax-error, parse-error

I've got a problem with my code and I'd like to get some help with it.

I've been trying to make a calculator, however this issue has occurred when trying to view the site.

```
"Parse Error: Syntax Error, unexpected ',' in C:// on line 14"
```

Underneath is part of my code, including where the error was indicated.

```
<?php

function add($num1,$num2,$num3,$num4)
{
    return ($num1,$num2,$num3,$num4); //error 
}

function clear(){
    return 0;
}

?>
```

The error I received is on line 14 which is where the return line is, which I pointed out in the code.

If you guys could help me out and say whats wrong about my code, why this error occurs and how to fix it, I'd really appreciate it!

If you need too see more code please tell me!

Comment: What are you trying to return?

Comment: if you are trying to retun addition of the numbers than return ($num1+$num2...) .. if you just want to concatenate return ($num1.$num2...) .. PHP parser does not understand ,(comma) unless it in side quotes or arrays..

Comment: return is language construct and not a function, it takes no parameters. Perhaps an array `return array($num1,...,...)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For returning a **String** you've to concat the return variables with dots:

```
function add($num1,$num2,$num3,$num4) {
    return $num1 . $num2 . $num3 . $num4; 
}
```

For returning an **Integer sum** you could sum it this way:

```
function add($num1,$num2,$num3,$num4) {
    return ($num1 + $num2 + $num3 + $num4); 
}
```

Returning an **Array** like this:

```
function add($num1,$num2,$num3,$num4) {
    return array($num1, $num2, $num3, $num4); 
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked :D
Thank you very much! Im new to the site but I cant accept it as an answer yet, I will do it later.

Comment: you're welcome. take your time! :-)